# Program closes for no apparent reason after typing one character

Tags: c, loops, goto

After typing 1 the program does this command printf("Janela ou porta?(j/p)"); and then closes for no apparent reason

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(){

    int resposta;
    char resp;
    ola:

    printf("Janela ou porta?(j/p)");

    scanf("%c",&resp);

    if (resp=='p'){

        printf("Go back(Type 1)");

        do{

            scanf("%d",&resposta);

        }while(resposta!=1);
        goto ola;

    }
}
```

Comment: Also, I suggest you avoid "goto" usage unless there are very specific optimization requirements.

Comment: If you don't see the prompt until *after* you enter the character, add `fflush(stdout)` after the `printf()` statement.

Comment: Also, you'll need to change `scanf("%c",&resp);` to `scanf(" %c",&resp);` note the added space. Please see [scanf() leaves the newline char in the buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240789/scanf-leaves-the-new-line-char-in-the-buffer). Some explanation: most of the format specifiers for `scanf` automatically filter leading whitespace, but `%c` and `%[]` and `%n` do not. Adding a space in front of the `%` instructs `scanf` to filter leading whitespace here too.

Answer (score 1):

When you input "1", "1" != "p" so you will never get to your while statement, you also won't trigger the goto statement. Like the other answer said, your program just ends.

Comment: The question asks why the prompt is not seen until after making the entry.